# Unable to integrate intl-tel-input - window.intlTelInput is not a function

Tags: npm-install, firebase-hosting, intl-tel-input

I'm trying to integrate intl-tel-input to support a phone number input field in an HTML form on my website. I installed the package using npm and my code looks like -

**HTML file (index.html)**

*inside head tag*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
```

*top of body*

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
```

*form section*

```
<div class="row">
          <form class="early-access-form" action="/early-access" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="form-field col-lg-2">

            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="middle-field col-lg-2">

            <input type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" class="middle-field col-lg-2">

            <input type="tel" id="phone">

            <script>

            var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
            var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
              separateDialCode:true,
              utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/utils.js",

            });

            </script>

            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="bottom-field col-lg-2">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-light form-button col-lg-2" type="submit" name="submit">Sign me up!</button>

          </form>
        </div>
```

This seems to work fine when I open the file in my browser. Screenshot of form -

[Screenshot of browser when I open the file from my system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2JAE.png)

However, post deployment through Firebase hosting, this seems to break and the same form looks like -

[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57wGj.png)

According to the DevTools console, the error is - 'window.intlTelInput is not a function'

I have already checked multiple solutions for the same error but I'm unable to make it work. Can somebody please point out the error, and why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need intlTelInput-jquery.min.js